# Unsupported Media Type with Array of Int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to pass an array of int to a get method on a Net Core 3.1 API project following the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Which states that you should pass the same param multiple times i.e
`selectedCourses=1050&selectedCourses=2000`

My URL looks like this:
`https://localhost:5001/api/products/featured?platforms=1&platforms=2`

I've also tried:
`https://localhost:5001/api/products/featured?platforms[0]=1&platforms[1]=2`

And here's my controller method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<ProductDTO>>> GetFeatured(int[] platforms)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(new GetFeaturedProductList.Query() { Platforms = platforms });
        }
```

I've also tried using a `List<int>` instead of `int[]` but to no avail.

But I keep getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type?

Comment: What does the server api documentation say?  Every API server is different and you must match the server requirements.

Comment: `415` error is returned when your server refuses to handle content of your request. What do you send in your `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding` request  headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add [FromUri] before parameter, looks like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ProductDTO>>> GetFeatured([FromUri] int[] platforms)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(new GetFeaturedProductList.Query() { Platforms = platforms });
    }
```

And the URL should be:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/products/featured?platforms=1&platforms=2
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It works but need to use [FromQuery] in Net core not [FromURI]. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkTallentire I think you can use [HttpGet] attribute for the method

Comment: @DmitryKolchev It already has [HttpGet("featured")] on it. I'm unsure why [FromQuery] seems to be needed because I understood the HttpGet to imply that as well.